# Series names highcharts

Tags: javascript

I have 2 questions.

1)  I'm trying to add specific series names, instead of the current titles, ' Series 1', 'Series 2' ...  How do I edit the javascript so I can include individual titles?

2)On the same chart how do I add X, Y and Z axes titles? The Z axis is the size of the bubble.

Thank you for any help.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pnbnmew4/1/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Recovery foods'
    },

    series: [{

        data: [[930, 58, 100], [94, 74, 60], [68, 76, 58], [64, 87, 56], [68, 27, 73], [74, 99, 42], [7, 93, 87], [51, 69, 40], [38, 23, 33], [57, 86, 31]]
    }, {
        data: [[25, 10, 87], [2, 75, 59], [11, 54, 8], [86, 55, 93], [5, 3, 58], [90, 63, 44], [91, 33, 17], [97, 3, 56], [15, 67, 48], [54, 25, 81]]
    }, {
        data: [[25, 10, 87], [2, 75, 59], [11, 54, 8], [86, 55, 93], [5, 3, 58], [90, 63, 44], [91, 33, 17], [97, 3, 56], [15, 67, 48], [54, 25, 81]]
    },
             {
        data: [[47, 47, 21], [20, 12, 4], [6, 76, 91], [38, 30, 60], [57, 98, 64], [61, 17, 80], [83, 60, 13], [67, 78, 75], [64, 12, 10], [30, 77, 82]]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, how do I indicate that the answer was helpful?

Comment: you can hit the check mark next to my answer to accept is as a solution. That way if future users of SO look at your question and have a similar problem they can quickly and easily locate a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking all you need is to customize the `xAxis`, `yAxis`, `tooltip`, and `series` attributes like so:

```
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Y-Axis Label"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "X-Axis Label"
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return "Size of bubble is " + this.y;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Specific Series 1",
            ...
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnbnmew4/3/) for a working fiddle.